# How to disable a button if all CheckedListbox items are unchecked

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable a button if the user unchecks all items in my CheckedListBox. Have a look at my code first:

```
void checkedListBoxChannels_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        if (this.checkedListBoxChannels.CheckedItems.Count == 0) {
            this.btnOK.Enabled = false;
        }
        else {
            this.btnOK.Enabled = true;
        }           
    }
```

The problem now is: When I uncheck the last checkbox and the check in the if block is done the CheckedItems.Count is still 1, so button wont get disabled. Same Problem when I check the first checkbox after no checkbox was checked. The Count is 0 and therefore my button is disabled.

So is there a possibility to find out the currently (after click of the user) checked or unchecked items of the CheckedListBox Control? I searched the EventArgs and sender properties but i couldnt find anything.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Ok i changed my code to:

```
if (this.checkedListBoxChannels.CheckedItems.Count == 1) {
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked) {
        this.btnOK.Enabled = false;
    }
} else {
    this.btnOK.Enabled = true;
}
```

now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the msdn documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Under 'Remarks' it says:
"The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs."
So it won't register your last change.
There are other events you could use. (Click or SelectedIndexChanged maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NewValue property of ItemCheckEventArgs e:

```
 private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 1)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            return;

        }

        //Last Item is uncheked
        if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 1 && e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        //First Item is checked
        if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 0 && e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

your condition should be

```
this.checkedListBoxChannels.CheckedItems.Count > 0
```

Comment: this isnt working. If I uncheck my last checkbox, the count is 1 and therefore the buttons is not getting disabled.